# SQL test if ARRAY contains integer

Tags: sql, arrays, hsqldb

I have a SQL TABLE like

```
CREATE TABLE Test ( ContentArray INTEGER ARRAY )`.
I can insert an column with `INSERT INTO Test ( ContentArray ) VALUES ( ARRAY[1,2,3,4] )
```

But I don't know how to get all columns where `ContentArray` contains integer 3.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO Test ( ContentArray ) VALUES ( ARRAY[1,2] )

INSERT INTO Test ( ContentArray ) VALUES ( ARRAY[3,4] )

INSERT INTO Test ( ContentArray ) VALUES ( ARRAY[4,5] )

INSERT INTO Test ( ContentArray ) VALUES ( ARRAY[5,6] )

SELECT ContentArray FROM Test WHERE /* ContentArray contains 5 and 6 */
```

should return `ARRAY[5,6]`.

Comment: Which RDMBS are you using?

Comment: Not sure what DBMS you are using, but it's almost always a bad idea to use array data types for fields in a relational database. The better choice is to store these values as children of the main table, then your query becomes simple.

Comment: Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: CREATE TABLE master (somekey INTEGER)
CREATE TABLE child (somekey INTEGER, value INTEGER)
INSERT INTO master (1)
INSERT INTO child (1,1)
INSERT INTO child (1,3)
INSERT INTO master (2)
INSERT INTO child (2,1)
INSERT INTO child (2,2)
INSERT INTO master (3)
INSERT INTO child (3,3)
SELECT * FROM master INNER JOIN child ON master.somekey = child.somekey where child.value = 3

Answer (score 2):

Given the DBMS and some quick research, it looks like SQL2008 supports the ANY keyword to allow this type of query for array datatypes:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE 3 = ANY (ContentArray);
```

I still wouldn't recommend using the array data type for anything non-trivial, I'm not sure what the performance of the above query would be like, but I'm sure it's not as good as a master table with children.

Comment: HSQLDB does not yet support `3 = ANY(ContentArray)`. It supports `3 IN(UNNEST(ContentsArray))` as well as `POSITION_ARRAY(3 IN ContentArray) > 0` which performs better

Comment: @fredt Thank you! I'll test what is faster ( and better for me ).

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Test WHERE POSITION_ARRAY(3 IN ContentArray) > 0 ` (617 ms) is faster than `SELECT * FROM Test WHERE 3 IN(UNNEST(ContentArray))` (2118 ms). (1,220,608 rows retrieved, total rows: 4,882,432). That is fast enough for me. :)