# How to update all rows where id is in array?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array with some numbers in it, 34, 12 and 23 for example.

Now I want to update all database rows where the id is in the array (when the id is 34, 12 and 23).

How do I accomplish this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, show your current attempt. PDO, preprared statement and multiple statement execution for each item in the array is a possible solution.

Comment: i would recommend to iterated through the array and update every single row within the loop with something like `foreach($some_array AS $some_value{ //TODO: update db row where $some_value}`. Of course you could also build the query within the loop and execute it after, then you got only one db access.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL test if ARRAY contains integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188842/sql-test-if-array-contains-integer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating multiple rows from ids array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315607/updating-multiple-rows-from-ids-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL you can filter `WHERE` with array by using>

```
WHERE column IN ('value1','value2','value3')
```

So you have to `implode` your array to string separated by commas. Something like this:

```php
$query = sprintf("UPDATE someTable SET anything=%s WHERE id IN ('%s')", $newValue, implode("','",$arrayOfIds));
$conn->query($query);
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me! And I learned something new.